# Is creating a Read Replica of another read replica supported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Shall i create a read replica from existing read replica in aws.

Kindly give the solution for above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I thought you couldn't, but it turns out that i**t is possible for MySQL**, whereas it isn't available for PostgreSQL:

There's [an announcement dated Aug 2013](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/08/28/amazon-rds-read-replica-new-features/) which says that you can create second tier read replicas to take some load off the master.

> You can now create a second-tier Read Replica from an existing
>   first-tier Read Replica. By creating a second-tier Read Replica, you
>   may be able to move some of the replication load from the master
>   database instance to a first-tier Read Replica. Please note that a
>   second-tier Read Replica may lag further behind the master because of
>   additional replication latency introduced as transactions are
>   replicated from the master to the first tier replica and then to the
>   second-tier replica.

Regarding Postgres, on which I based my first answer, I'm positive you can't.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @amenadiel but i have one more doubt is it possible for MySQL database ?

Comment: Thank you so much @amenadiel

Answer (score 0):

There are further changes. Now you can read replicas for more DBs

From: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

> Q: Can I create a Read Replica of another Read Replica?
>
> Amazon Aurora, Amazon RDS for MySQL and MariaDB: You can create a
>   second-tier Read Replica from an existing first-tier Read Replica. By
>   creating a second-tier Read Replica, you may be able to move some of
>   the replication load from the master database instance to a first-tier
>   Read Replica. Please note that a second-tier Read Replica may lag
>   further behind the master because of additional replication latency
>   introduced as transactions are replicated from the master to the first
>   tier replica and then to the second-tier replica.
>
> Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL: Read Replicas of Read Replicas are not
>   currently supported.